# focusedSceneValue fixed by searchable

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm getting this odd issue where `focusedSceneValue` doesn't work on macOS Monterey Beta 6, but adding `searchable` to one of the views fixes it.

Here's how to reproduce:

First paste this code into `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var search = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("First")
                .focusedSceneValue(\.customAction) {
                    print("Pressed!")
                }
            Text("Second")
                .searchable(text: $search) // Comment this line and focusedSceneValue breaks
        }
    }
}

struct ActionKey: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = () -> Void
}
extension FocusedValues {
    var customAction: (() -> Void)? {
        get { self[ActionKey.self] }
        set { self[ActionKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

And then paste this into your app file:

```
struct CustomCommands: Commands {
    @FocusedValue(\.customAction) var action
    
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(before: .newItem) {
            Button(action: {
                action?()
            }) {
                Text("Press me")
            }
            .disabled(action == nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And add this into the body of your `Scene`:

```
.commands {
    CustomCommands()
}
```

This just adds a menu item to `File`, and the menu item is enabled only if a variable named `action` is not nil.

`action` is supposed to be assigned in the `focusedSceneValue` line in `ContentView`. This should always happen, as long as the `ContentView` is visible.

This code only works if I add the `searchable` modifier to one of the views however. If I don't add it, then the menu item is permanently disabled.

Is anybody else able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug with implementing `focusedSceneValue` ([SwiftUI and focusedSceneValue on macOS, what am I doing wrong?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693580)).

From what you have shared, it seems that the `.searchable` modifier provides a focus for a view in the scene so that the `focusedSceneValue` is updated when the focus changes.

In the [`focusedSceneValue` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/focusedscenevalue%28_%3A_%3A%29), it recommends using this method "for values that must be visible regardless of where focus is located in the active scene." Implicitly, it could be that `focusedSceneValue` only works when an active scene has focus somewhere within.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in Monterey 12.1 (21C52), so the `.searchable` workaround should no longer be needed.